# Cat pulls his claws off while being transported

Tags: cats, behavior, travel

My cat hates the car and his travel box (plastic with wire mesh). He claws at the boxes air vents / grill and goes a bit crazy when we drive, which leads to pulled off claw sheaths and a bit of bleeding. How do I stop him from doing this? Is there any solution other than sedating him?

Comment: Kitten mittens?

Comment: Does this only happen when you're driving, or does it happen whenever he's confined to the carrier? Also, when you put him in the carrier, does he seem frightened?

Comment: Only when I'm driving. When I put him in he seems distressed, when I drive he seems to be genuinely frightened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest cutting the cat's claws immediately before transporting him.  Make sure to use proper clippers designed for use on cats.  Another suggestion is to get a different cat carrier, one that the cat is less likely to get their claws caught on.  They make tote bag type carriers that are constructed from heavy cloth materials like nylon rather than hard plastics, which may work better for him.  You could also try covering particular problem areas with a towel or something, as long as it doesn't block all the carrier's ventilation.  Cloth is of course porous, so air could get through, but it might become too hot if all openings are completely covered.

Comment: I always cover the carrier with a towel.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a product called Feliway? It is plugged into the wall and is used for stressful situations. They also have a spray and suggest spraying the carrier a few minutes before you travel. You can read more about it both on the Feliway site and Amazon. It's on cheap.